# ROLLBACK after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do not understand why the create method is throwing me a ROLLBACK with those parameters...

[image: error_create]

The model have the following validations...

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  #model validations
  validates :title,              presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
  validates :required,           presence: true
  validates :has_other,          presence: true, inclusion: [true, false]
  validates :position,           presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  validates :question_cluster,   presence: true

  #model relations
  has_many   :options
  belongs_to :question_cluster
end
```

**Is there a way to know specifically why the create is not being accepted?**

**EDIT:**

With `errors.full_messages` I get `["Has other can't be blank"]`, why is this happening?

**EDIT 2:**

From schema.rb

```
create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title",               limit: 255
  t.boolean  "required"
  t.boolean  "has_other"
  t.integer  "position"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "question_cluster_id"
end
```

By the way, I noted that if I try to create a question with `"has_other"=>true` it works fine, but with `"has_other"=>false` I got the error, the validation I did is right?

Comment: do like `q = Question.new({..attributes..}); q.valid?; p q.errors.full_messages`. This will tell you where it is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, it's telling me this: `["Has other can't be blank"]`, any idea why?

Comment: What is the datatype of `has_other` field?

Comment: @cursillosonline show the part of this table from schema.rb file.

Comment: Ok, I added that part, btw, if I use `"has_other"=>true` it works fine, I just realized that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on this [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence)

> Since false.blank? is true, if you want to validate the presence of a boolean field you should use one of the following validations:

```
validates :boolean_field_name, presence: true
validates :boolean_field_name, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
validates :boolean_field_name, exclusion: { in: [nil] }
```

So your validation would be one of these:

```
validates :has_other, presence: true
validates :has_other, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
validates :has_other, exclusion: { in: [nil] }
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that `validates :has_other, presence: true` excludes the fact that it may be false, now is working as expected with just `validates :has_other, inclusion: [true, false]`